# How to add css class to Jquery ui plugin dropdownchecklist

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using 
http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/
And when dynamically disabling it (in some scenario), want it to be gray..
tried to use .addClass but didn't work..
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DDCL plugin has built-in support for disabling/enabling the widget.  Simply call the `dropdownchecklist` method on your original select element with the `'disable'` parameter:

```
$('#myselect').dropdownchecklist('disable');
// to enable:
$('#myselect').dropdownchecklist('enable');
```

When disabled, clicking the widget will not cause the dropdown to open, and the class `ui-state-disabled` is applied to the widget control element.  With the default ThemeRoller CSS files, the control will have an `opacity` so that it appears dimmed.  You could customize this appearance in your own CSS with `.ui-dropdownchecklist-selector.ui-state-disabled { ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

It works ok form, so I suppose there's something you're doing wrong.

I imagine you have `.gray{ color: #ccc;}` in your CSS. Then, when you initialize Dropdown CheckList plugin, you'll have a call more or less like this:

```
$("#mydropdown").dropdownchecklist();
```

If you try `$("#mydropdown").dropdownchecklist().addClass("gray")`, you're adding the class to the **original** dropdown.

The new dropdown control defaults with the `id` prefix `ddcl-XXX` (**D** rop **d** own **C** heck **L** ist), being XXX the `id`of the *real* dropdown. Knowing this, try the following:

```
$("#mydropdown").dropdownchecklist();
$("#ddcl-mydropdown").addClass("gray");
```

Answer (score -1):

Having not seen the code I'd suggest using $('example').attr('class', 'class_you_are_adding');  Sometimes .addclass doesn't work like you would expect.  Being more explicit solves the problem.

Comment: What do you mean `addClass` doesn't always work like you might expect?  It *always* adds the specified class(es) to the element.  Using `attr('class', ...)` would have side effects because it *overwrites* what is already there.

Comment: @josh373 I'm just saying that there have been instances before when .addclass did not work like I expected.  Depending on what you are doing and how you are doing it attr('class', ...) can be an effective solution.  I'm not saying there aren't other ways of doing this, I'm just offering a possible solution.  I thought that's what this site was here for.

Comment: This is not an effective solution because there is a significant difference between `addClass(...)` and `attr('class', ...)`, which you completely gloss over: adding classes vs setting classes.  The latter is a destructive operation (which is why we have `addClass` in the first place).  In this case, using `attr` would overwrite the classes the plugin adds to the widget element -- `ui-dropdownchecklist ui-dropdownchecklist-selector-wrapper ui-widget` -- which would break the widget's styling.  For proper ThemeRoller compatibility, the class `ui-state-disabled` needs to be **added**.

Comment: Also, regarding your experience `addClass`: There's absolutely nothing that should be 'unexpected'.  Given a space-delimited list of CSS classes, `addClass` will merge those classes into the classes already set on each of the matched elements.  (In other words, if an element already has a class that you're trying to add, the class will not be duplicated.)  [Take a look at the actual function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.1/src/attributes.js#L39) -- there's no surprises.

Comment: ...that said, if you *want* to **clear** an element's CSS classes and set new ones, you're right, `attr('class', ...)` is the correct approach.  However, that's not what we want to do in this case, and you should be more explicit about the difference in your approach when suggesting it.